# Can DataGrab check for duplicate entries using entry_id or url_title?

Tags: datagrab

I went to set up a data import for a CSV to bulk update product prices and discovered that there is no option to check for duplicates on `exp_channel_titles.entry_id` or `exp_channel_titles.url_title`.

This feature only seems to work on custom fields in the channel's field group.

Unfortunately this product list does not have any real-world product code or similar unique identification system so using the `entry_id` or `url_title` would be ideal.

I'm using plain old channels here and not using third-party add-ons for this channel.

Is this something that can be done using DataGrab or will I need to add this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly "title" is something you can key off when doing the import.

Comment: My issue with the title is it only takes a spelling mistake (or 'fix') in the CSV to end up with duplicated database entries. The `entry_id` is something a spreadsheet user would be more hesitant to mess about with :) .

Comment: How about creating a new column that matches to a field to hold an ID that is only used for the import?

Comment: The thought had crossed my mind but it seems to me that this is something that could be supported by the add-on without duplicating data. I've set up other DataGrab import configurations for the site and this wasn't a problem as the client would be using a real-world product code to prevent duplicates. I'll see if this is something that is already present in DataGrab or failing that I'll try and hack it in.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the late reply here! If you look here - http://brandnewbox.co.uk/forums/viewthread/785/ Andrew claims that this is available. I cannot see it in the new version i've downloaded but if you ping @ajweaver he might be able to furnish you with a copy that has this?